# How to mark a number of checkboxes as checked and others unchecked in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays

masterList:

```
[
  { id: 0, description: "a" },
  { id: 1, description: "b" },
  { id: 2, description: "c" },
  { id: 3, description: "d" }
]
```

preferencesList:

```
[
  {id: 0, description: "a" },
  {id: 2, description: "c" }
]
```

What I want to do is, render four checkboxes (or more, depending on the length of masterList) and pre-check only those checkboxes that are listed in preferencesList.

I tried  but couldn't get it to work.

This is what I have done so far:

```
{
  this.state.masterList && this.state.masterList.length ? (
    this.state.masterList.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={`item_${index}`} className="form-group">
        <div className="checkbox">
          <label>
            {this.state.preferencesList && this.state.preferencesList.length
              ? this.state.preferencesList.map(
                  insurerFeature =>
                    insurerFeature.id == item.id ? (
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        onChange={this.changeFeaturePreferences}
                        value={item.id}
                        defaultChecked
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        onChange={this.changeFeaturePreferences}
                        value={item.id}
                      />
                    )
                )
              : "failed to get insurers items"}
            {item.description}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))
  ) : (
    <p>There are no items available.</p>
  );
}
```

changeFeaturePreferences Method:

```
changeFeaturePreferences = event => {
  let { id } = this.state.resource;
  let featureId = event.target.value;
  let checkbox = event.target;

  // Reset state
  this.setState({ success: null });

  // Add Feature
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    let payload = [featureId];
    return MyService.setMyFeatures(id, payload).then(
      response => this.setState({ success: true }),
      error => this.setState({ success: false })
    );
  }
  // Remove Feature
  if (!checkbox.checked) {
    return MyService.deleteMyFeatures(id, featureId).then(
      response => this.setState({ success: true }),
      error => this.setState({ success: false })
    );
  }
  // Return with error
  return this.setState({ success: false });
};
```

Comment: You should first try to extract every map and JSX pieces to its own function in order to have a better view of what and how they are called. It will help you structure your algorithm and thoughts.

Comment: Can you add the code for your `changeFeaturePreferences` method?

Comment: @RossAllen added the code for changeFeaturePreferences method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to determine if the object exists in `preferencesList`.

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array
>   passes the test implemented by the provided function.

**Example**

```
{
  this.state.masterList && this.state.masterList.length ? (
    this.state.masterList.map((item, index) => {
      const checked = preferencesList.some((checkedItem) => checkedItem.id === item.id);
      return (
      <div key={`item_${index}`} className="form-group">
        <div className="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={this.changeFeaturePreferences}
              value={item.id}
              checked={checked}
            />
            {item.description}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    )})
  ) : (
    <p>There are no items available.</p>
  );
}
```

Comment: This will definitely work and with what seems likely to be a short list, there's no problem doing it this way. It does have a run time of `O(n*m)` / `O(n^2)` though (where `n = masterList.length` and `m =  preferencesList.length`. If you first convert the `preferencesList` to an Object, which has constant time lookup, you would get `O(n) + O(m)` -> `2O(n)` -> `O(n)` run time.

Comment: @RossAllen you are definitely right. I discovered that right after saw your answer but kept it since its an alternative way to solve the problem. Thank you for the pointing it out.

Comment: @bennygenel this works, however, if I try to check an unchecked box, the function associated to it gets executed but the check doesn't appear

Comment: @AjayGupta Does your `changeFeaturePreferences` method take an ID as an argument? You likely need to partially apply the method like, `onChange={this.changeFeaturePreferences.bind(this, item.id)}`.

Comment: @AjayGupta checked value is set with the contents of the preferencesList array. you need to update it accordingly in state so the checked value also changes

Answer (score 2):

I would first convert the `preferencesList` into an Object so you have constant-time look up after the initial mapping and simpler logic in your JSX. You could do something like the following:

```
const isChecked = {};
preferencesList.forEach(preference => { isChecked[preference.id] = true; });

{
  this.state.masterList && this.state.masterList.length ? (
    this.state.masterList.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={`item_${index}`} className="form-group">
        <div className="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={this.changeFeaturePreferences}
              value={item.id}
              defaultChecked={isChecked[item.id]}
            />
            {item.description}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))
  ) : (
    <p>There are no items available.</p>
  );
}
```